# Android sqlite query not returning what it should

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

This has been bothering me for a while know, and I cannot seem to figure it out.

I'm working with calendar, and when certain day is clicked I'm calling a map with events of that day and drawing marker for each event.

```
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String date_clicked = extras.getString("PASSED_DATE");
    title.setText(date_clicked);

    dbHelper helper = new dbHelper(getApplicationContext());
    Cursor cursor = helper.getAllEventsByDay(this, date_clicked);
    Log.d("MapsActivity", "date_clicked " + date_clicked);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
            String row_loc = cursor.getString(0);
            String row_title = cursor.getString(1);
            Log.d("DayEvents", "row_loc " + row_loc);
            if (!row_loc.isEmpty()) {
                LatLng hcmus = getLocationFromAddress(getApplicationContext(), row_loc);
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(hcmus, 18));
                originMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .title(row_title)
                        .position(hcmus)));
            }
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }

mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

}
```

I have couple events in database at X days of this month which starts and ends at the same day.

Funny thing is, map does now show those events of clicked day when I have AND operator in the query, but when I put OR instead of AND, the map shows me all the events of every day.

So where could be a problem? The query should be correct, for example if I have events at 18th day lasting till the same 18th, it would look like this: `where start_date<=2016-05-18 AND end_date>=2016-05-18` and therefore should return all events of that day, Instead it does not take anything from database...

`dbHelper.java` cursor:

```
    public Cursor getAllEventsByDay(Activity activity,String date) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String from[] = { eventai.InsertNewEvent.LOCATION, eventai.InsertNewEvent.EVENT, eventai.InsertNewEvent.START_TIME};
    String where = eventai.InsertNewEvent.START_DATE+" <= "+date+" AND "+eventai.InsertNewEvent.END_DATE+">= "+date;
    Cursor cursor = db.query(eventai.InsertNewEvent.TABLE_NAME, from, where, null, null, null, null, null);
    Log.d("MapsActivity", "CURSOR " + from + where);
    return cursor;
}
```

I need to mention that all my db field are TEXT, and date format that I'm  getting as `String date` is yyyy-MM-dd, the same goes for database fields `START_DATE` and `END_DATE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should actually be a comment. But I don't have enough rep to comment. So posting this as a answer.

Try changing the where clause to

```
eventai.InsertNewEvent.START_DATE+" >= "+date+" AND "+eventai.InsertNewEvent.END_DATE+" <= "+date;
```

from

```
eventai.InsertNewEvent.START_DATE+" <= "+date+" AND "+eventai.InsertNewEvent.END_DATE+">= "+date;
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was missing single quotes here, so the sollution is the following:

```
eventai.InsertNewEvent.START_DATE+" <= '"+date+"' AND "+eventai.InsertNewEvent.END_DATE+" >= '"+date+"'";
```

But this is not a full solution... I get only rows, where start_date < date and end_date > date, but I do not get rows where date equals start and end dates...